# Implementing Mutex Lock Without Busy Waiting

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex

I got a university assignment to implement a Mutex lock without busy waiting. I am trying to implement it but without much success. Sometimes, it throws segmentation overflow other time it just keeps hanging however, when I run it in gdb it runs perfectly every time.

**mutex.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define NUM_THREADS 2

// shared data structure
int sum = 0;

struct Stack waiting_q;

bool mutex_locked = false;

void * got_signal(int x) { return NULL; }

void acquire()
{
    bool first_time = true;
    while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&mutex_locked, false, true))
    {
        if (first_time)
        {
            push(&waiting_q, pthread_self());
            first_time = false;
        }
        printf("%ld is waiting for mutex\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));
        pause();
    }
    printf("Mutex acquired by %ld\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));
}

void release()
{
    int thread_r = pop(&waiting_q);
    if (waiting_q.size != 0 && thread_r != INT_MIN)
        pthread_kill(thread_r, SIGCONT);

    mutex_locked = false;
    printf("Mutex released by = %ld\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));
}

void * work()
{
    acquire();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + 1;
    }
    release();
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    init_stack(&waiting_q);
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, work, NULL);
        if (rc != 0)
            printf("Error creating thread\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Value of Sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**stack.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Node{
    struct Node * next;
    pthread_t x;
};

struct Stack{
    struct Node * head;
    int size;
};

void push(struct Stack * s, pthread_t n)
{
    struct Node * new_head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_head->next = s->head;
    new_head->x = n;
    s->head = new_head;
    s->size++;
}

pthread_t pop(struct Stack * s)
{
    pthread_t rc = INT_MIN;
    if (s->head != NULL)
    {
        rc = s->head->x;
        struct Node * next = s->head->next;
        free(s->head);
        s->head = next;
        return rc;
    }
    s->size--;
    return rc;
}

void init_stack(struct Stack * s)
{
    s->head = 0;
    s->size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Try passing `-fsanitize=undefined,address` to compiler and linker. If you are lucky you will get more helpful output.

Comment: @nwp It either hangs totally or works correctly.

Comment: Having the `push` inside a `while`-loop could generate a huge amount of pushes. Also, the code in `push` and `pop` doesn't seem to be thread safe. What if you do `free(s->head)` just as the other thread adds a new `head`?

Comment: @BoPersson How can I make them thread safe?

Comment: @AhmedBilal Learning how to do that was probably pretty much the whole point of that university course of yours.

Comment: Why is this marked as C++ when this is pure C? Please don't tag spam

Comment: @Ahmed - You will likely have to use some kind of lock.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Access to your `Stack` data structure from the mutex implementation is not synchronized.

Multiple threads could attempt to `acquire` the mutex at the same time, which will lead to them accessing `waiting_q` concurrently. Similarly, a releasing thread's `pop()` access to `waiting_q` is not synchronized with the `push()` access from the acquiring threads.

This data race on the `Stack` is most likely what is causing the segfault.

Comment: Actually, any data structure would work. I just want to keep track of threads that I paused to later wake them up.

Comment: @AhmedBilal The problem is not the data structure but the lack of synchronization. You would get similar crashes with any other (non-thread safe) data structure.

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: @AhmedBilal By using a thread-safe data structure or inserting additional synchronization mechanisms. Honestly, there's a million different ways to fix this, but I don't know which of them is appropriate for your problem. I'd suggest you visit the office hours of your course advisor and discuss the problem with them. If you can demonstrate that you understood where your solution is lacking, I'm sure they will be more than happy to give you a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: @AhmedBilal The order of joins should not be of concern here, as all threads behave symmetrical (ie. execute the exact same `work` function). If order of threads *were* to be an issue (which it's not), you would be in big trouble: Since both threads execute the same function, they can 'switch places' at will. If you `join`ed in the opposite order, they could simply rearrange their schedules in a way that the original problem manifests again.

Comment: @AhmedBilal Because gdb influences the scheduling of the individual threads, often hiding data races as a result. That is one of the reasons why multi-threaded programs have a reputation for being difficult to debug.